# what is the best practice from Cloudera to migrate the parquet-based impala to kudu-based impala

Tags: cloudera, impala, apache-kudu

We are using Cloudera as our hadoop environment.

Can someone please provide any guildance on how to integrate or migrate existing parquet/impala to kudu/impala to hopefully get a performance improvement to our existing pipeline?

Our existing pipeline is brief'ed here:

We receive data in the format of csv/xlsx;

- We move them onto HDFS;
- We save them to another location in the format of parquet;
- We create external table in impala with the location pointing to the partitioned parquet data;
- We do our ETL jobs within pyspark, spark scala, spark sql;
- We output our analytical result to csv.

Existing pipeline is working as expected, however, as data maintains an ongoing growth, the time/resource needed for the pipeline also increases.

We are wondering what is the best practice to migrate the parquet-based impala to kudu-based impala for a better overall performance?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Th question is vague. You can insert from Hive to KUDU bypassing parquet. Is the question about Hive/Parquet or about scalability?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. Yeah, I guess I can select the data from parquet to a new kudu-based table.

Comment: Why do both?????

Comment: Because this is an existing project, all the data is currently stored as parquet, I am wondering if by storing them to Kudu would improve the performance (multiple tables have million/billion rows). btw, would you please provide a working example of CTAS here and I will accept it as Answer. Thank you.

Comment: Before going down that path, have you reviewed Kudu's own limitations? https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/kudu_limitations.html#scaling_limits AFAIK, Impala/Parquet scales much farther, and real Kudu advantage is data updateability.

Comment: I checked internally and was told we will hold it for CDH be upgraded to 6, thank you all.